# How to use google translation offline in php?

Tags: php, input, local, offline, transliteration

I've developed some web forms which is using Google translation and it's works fine. but now my client want to put that application on a separate server which is Internet not available. can I use Google translation locally? Google input tools are not good for this one because language is selected by my php code (by language selection buttons, variable in session).
can you help me?
Thanks

Comment: no , you can not